# HTTP verb for appending to a resource object?

Tags: api, rest, json-api

I am trying build an api which conforms to the [json:api](https://jsonapi.org/) spec.

My api has three resources `/task`, `/item` and `/result`. A task has the fields `name`, `description` and `state`. A item has the fields `itemName`. A `count` is kept server-site for the item and the `count` is returned when a user retrieves the item with a `GET` request. The `count` is incremented server-side when the item is updated. There is a one-to-many relationship between task and item. In a sense an item is appended to a task. When the tasks state changes a script runs server-side to do some processing on the associated items. Once the script finishes the output is available in the result resource.

Per the spec, I am using the `POST` verb to create a task and the `PATCH` to update a task. I just want one endpoint which handles both the create /update (appending) of an item. But, I'm not sure which verb to use? Can I use `PATCH` to update the item but also create an item if it doesn't exist?

I also thought that perhaps I should be using the `PUT` verb. But, my understanding here is that this verb is used to simply replace a resource rather than update it. I don't think this is right for my user-case as an items count is incremented when updated, so replacing it is not what I want todo. But, the count is handled server-side so a user doesn't have the option of "replacing" the count anyway.

Comment: I'm not fully sure if I understand correctly what "create /update (appending) of an item" means. Are you looking for a way to create an `item` and assign it to a given `task` with only one request?

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at here is can the `PATCH` verb create a resource if it does not already exist? The RFC 5789 link in VoiceOfUnreason answer suggests that it can "If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, the server MAY create a new resource". Not sure if this is valid in json:api however.

Comment: Im also not sure how you handle server-side only fields in json:api. The `count` field in my example is maintained on the server-side. The client can retrieve the `count` in the `GET` response but they are not able to ever actually set the value of count. Count is just incremented every time that item is re-posted.

Comment: I still didn't got your use case. Why do you want to use the same endpoint to create a resource if it does not exist yet or update it if it exists? Are you thinking about changing the has-one side of a relationship but don't care about if it exists before? Read-only fields is another topic. A server can include whatever fields they like in the response. A server may ignore any field included in the request. You should only make sure to include the full resource in response to create or update of the resource to inform the client about the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my understanding here is that this verb is used to simply replace a resource rather than update it.

This is a common understanding - wrong, but common.

The IANA registry documents the authoritative reference for the semantics of [http methods](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml).  Most of the common ones are defined by [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3); PATCH is defined by [RFC 5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789).

[PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) is an appropriate choice when the message body is a complete representation of what you want the resource to be.  It may be easier to think about "saving a file"; PUT describes what the client expects the document to look like when it has been saved.

It's appropriate to use PUT for either updating a document or creating one, provided that the client knows the identifier for the document (just in the same way that we can use save to create a file, or replace a file, but we need to know the file name).

If you read the text of the specification, you'll see that - while the semantics of the request are to save the new representation "as-is", the server isn't required to do that -- the server, after all, is in control of its own documents -- so there is room to cover read only fields, or fields that should be updated by the server only.  You need to have a little bit of care with the response headers to avoid implying that you saved the representation as is, but other than that you should be fine.

Comment: Can you please cite the parts of the JSON API specification you are basing your answer on? As far as I know the specification does not mention `PUT` anywhere. It uses `POST` to create and `PATCH` to update. [In FAQ](https://jsonapi.org/faq/#wheres-put) it gives explicit reasons why `PUT` is not used in the specification.